# How to authorize google-api-php-client with a slim 3 Rest API?

Tags: php, authentication, slim, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to create a web-based email client which gets all email data from google mail API. I'm using Slim3 for creating a restful API interface. To access google APIs, I'm using Google-API-PHP-Client (Google does have a rest API access and I really like it but I still haven't figured out how the authorization would work without using the PHP-client-library).

My main problem is how do I structure authentication part of it as google uses Oauth2 for login which gives a code. I can use a simple token based auth in Slim but then how do I achieve the following:

1. Authentication/Authorization with google.
2. Identifying new vs returning users.
3. Maintaining & Retaining both access and refresh tokens from google and local APIs
4. Since the API will be used on both mobile clients and web-browser, I can't use PHP's default sessions - I'm relying on database driven custom tokens.

How do I structure the APIs?

One way was to use google's token as the only token in the app - but it keeps changing every hour so How do I identify the user from token - calling google API for every incoming call doesn't seem like a graceful solution.

Any leads/links would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will help you with point one http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/   Just store the refresh token on your system it will allow you to get a new access token.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks, this article focuses acquiring a refresh token. I can already do that using PHP-API-SDK with a simple method call. What got me stuck is how to structure the services.

Comment: Check https://github.com/akrabat/slim-bookshelf-api for inspiration.

Comment: @MikaTuupola thanks!!! 
I'll fork and try implementing third party feature of this one. Will post an update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are 2 parts:

1. Authorization
2. Authentication

I recently created this very lightweight class for **Authorization** using Google, accessing its REST API. It is self-explanatory with the comments.

```
/**
 * Class \Aptic\Login\OpenID\Google
 * @package Aptic\Login\OpenID
 * @author Nick de Jong, Aptic
 *
 * Very lightweight class used to login using Google accounts.
 *
 * One-time configuration:
 *  1. Define what the inpoint redirect URIs will be where Google will redirect to upon succesfull login. It must
 *     be static without wildcards; but can be multiple as long as each on is statically defined.
 *  2. Define what payload-data this URI could use. For example, the final URI to return to (the caller).
 *  3. Create a Google Project through https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials
 *  4. Create a Client ID OAth 2.0 with type 'webapp' through https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials
 *  5. Store the 'Client ID', 'Client Secret' and defined 'Redirect URIs' (the latter one as defined in Step 1).
 *
 * Usage to login and obtain user data:
 *  1. Instantiate a class using your stored Client ID, Client Secret and a Redirect URI.
 *  2. To login, create a button or link with the result of ->getGoogleLoginPageURI() as target. You can insert
 *     an array of payload data in one of the parameters your app wants to know upon returning from Google.
 *  3. At the Redirect URI, invoke ->getDataFromLoginRedirect(). It will return null on failure,
 *     or an array on success. The array contains:
 *       - sub             string  Google ID. Technically an email is not unique within Google's realm, a sub is.
 *       - email           string
 *       - name            string
 *       - given_name      string
 *       - family_name     string
 *       - locale          string
 *       - picture         string  URI
 *       - hdomain         string  GSuite domain, if applicable.
 *     Additionally, the inpoint can recognize a Google redirect by having the first 6 characters of the 'state' GET
 *     parameter to be 'google'. This way, multiple login mechanisms can use the same redirect inpoint.
 */
class Google {
  protected $clientID       = '';
  protected $clientSecret   = '';
  protected $redirectURI    = '';

  public function __construct($vClientID, $vClientSecret, $vRedirectURI) {
    $this->clientID = $vClientID;
    $this->clientSecret = $vClientSecret;
    $this->redirectURI = $vRedirectURI;
    if (substr($vRedirectURI, 0, 7) != 'http://' && substr($vRedirectURI, 0, 8) != 'https://') $this->redirectURI = 'https://'.$this->redirectURI;
  }

  /**
   * @param string $vSuggestedEmail
   * @param string $vHostedDomain   Either a GSuite hosted domain, * to only allow GSuite domains but accept all, or null to allow any login.
   * @param array $aPayload         Payload data to be returned in getDataFromLoginRedirect() result-data on succesfull login. Keys are not stored, only values. Example usage: Final URI to return to after succesfull login (some frontend).
   * @return string
   */
  public function getGoogleLoginPageURI($vSuggestedEmail = null, $vHostedDomain = '*', $aPayload = []) {
    $vLoginEndpoint  = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '?state=google-'.self::encodePayload($aPayload);
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '&prompt=consent'; // or: select_account
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '&response_type=code';
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '&scope=openid+email+profile';
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '&access_type=offline';
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '&client_id='.$this->clientID;
    $vLoginEndpoint .= '&redirect_uri='.$this->redirectURI;

    if ($vSuggestedEmail) $vLoginEndpoint .= '&login_hint='.$vSuggestedEmail;
    if ($vHostedDomain)   $vLoginEndpoint .= '&hd='.$vHostedDomain;
    return($vLoginEndpoint);
  }

  /**
   * Call this function directly from the redirect URI, which is invoked after a call to getGoogleLoginPageURL().
   * You can either provide the code/state GET parameters manually, otherwise it will be retrieved from GET automatically.
   * Returns an array with:
   *  - sub             string  Google ID. Technically an email is not unique within Google's realm, a sub is.
   *  - email           string
   *  - name            string
   *  - given_name      string
   *  - family_name     string
   *  - locale          string
   *  - picture         string  URI
   *  - hdomain         string  G Suite domain
   *  - payload         array   The payload originally provided to ->getGoogleLoginPageURI()
   * @param null|string $vCode
   * @param null|string $vState
   * @return null|array
   */
  public function getDataFromLoginRedirect($vCode = null, $vState = null) {
    $vTokenEndpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
    if ($vCode === null)  $vCode  = $_GET['code'];
    if ($vState === null) $vState = $_GET['state'];
    if (substr($vState, 0, 7) !== 'google-') {
      trigger_error('Invalid state-parameter from redirect-URI. Softfail on login.', E_USER_WARNING);
      return(null);
    }
    $aPostData = [
        'code' => $vCode,
        'client_id' => $this->clientID,
        'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
        'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectURI,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
    ];
    curl_setopt_array($hConn = curl_init($vTokenEndpoint), [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => defined('PROJECT_ID') && defined('API_CUR_VERSION') ? PROJECT_ID.' '.API_CUR_VERSION : 'Aptic\Login\OpenID\Google PHP-class',
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POST           => 1
    ]);
    curl_setopt($hConn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($aPostData));
    $aResult = json_decode(curl_exec($hConn), true);
    curl_close($hConn);
    if (is_array($aResult) && array_key_exists('access_token', $aResult) && array_key_exists('refresh_token', $aResult) && array_key_exists('expires_in', $aResult)) {
      $aUserData = explode('.', $aResult['id_token']); // Split JWT-token
      $aUserData = json_decode(base64_decode($aUserData[1]), true); // Decode JWT-claims from part-1 (without verification by part-0).
      if ($aUserData['exp'] < time()) {
        trigger_error('Received an expired ID-token. Softfail on login.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return(null);
      }
      $aRet = [
          // 'access_token'  => $aResult['access_token'],
          // 'expires_in'    => $aResult['expires_in'],
          // 'refresh_token' => $aResult['refresh_token'],
          'sub'           => array_key_exists('sub',          $aUserData) ? $aUserData['sub']         : '',
          'email'         => array_key_exists('email',        $aUserData) ? $aUserData['email']       : '',
          'name'          => array_key_exists('name',         $aUserData) ? $aUserData['name']        : '',
          'given_name'    => array_key_exists('given_name',   $aUserData) ? $aUserData['given_name']  : '',
          'family_name'   => array_key_exists('family_name',  $aUserData) ? $aUserData['family_name'] : '',
          'locale'        => array_key_exists('locale',       $aUserData) ? $aUserData['locale']      : '',
          'picture'       => array_key_exists('picture',      $aUserData) ? $aUserData['picture']     : '',
          'hdomain'       => array_key_exists('hd',           $aUserData) ? $aUserData['hd']          : '',
          'payload'       => self::decodePayload($vState)
      ];

      return($aRet);
    } else {
      trigger_error('OpenID Connect Login failed.', E_USER_WARNING);
      return(null);
    }
  }

  protected static function encodePayload($aPayload) {
    $aPayloadHEX = [];
    foreach($aPayload as $vPayloadEntry) $aPayloadHEX[] = bin2hex($vPayloadEntry);
    return(implode('-', $aPayloadHEX));
  }

  /**
   * You generally do not need to call this method from outside this class; only if you
   * need your payload *before* calling ->getDataFromLoginRedirect().
   * @param string $vStateParameter
   * @return array
   */
  public static function decodePayload($vStateParameter) {
    $aPayload = explode('-', $vStateParameter);
    $aRetPayload = [];
    for($i=1; $i<count($aPayload); $i++) $aRetPayload[] = hex2bin($aPayload[$i]);
    return($aRetPayload);
  }

}
```

As soon as the function `getDataFromLoginRedirect` does return user data, your user is **Authorized**. This means you can now issue your own internal authentication token.

So, for **Authentication**, maintain your own data table of users with either `sub` or `email` as primary identifier and issue tokens for them, with appropriate expire mechanisms. The Google tokens themselves do not necessarily be stored, as they are only required for subsequent Google API calls; which depend on your use case. For your own application though, your own token mechanism will suffice for authentication.

To get back to your questions:

*Authentication/Authorization with google.*

Described above.

*Identifying new vs returning users.*

Can be determined by the existence of the user in your data table.

*Maintaining & Retaining both access and refresh tokens from google and local APIs*

Ask yourself the question whether you really need to. If so, you could either refresh upon every x requests, or refresh once the expiry time is in less than x minutes (i.e. this will be your application's timeout in that case). If you really require your tokens to remain valid, you should setup a daemon-mechanism that periodically refreshes your users tokens.